# Angular directive : DOM manipulation for SVG element

Tags: angularjs, dom, directive

I'm having an issue trying to manipulate elements into a SVG from an Angular 1.x directive.

**Sidenote** : I m trying to display static values on the bars drawn by Chartist via Angular.

Here is the HTML markup  (sorry for formating, it breaks code style if I insert line feed):

```
<chartist class="ct-chart ct-minor-seventh chartBarLabel ng-isolate-scope" chartist-data="testData" chartist-chart-type="Bar" chartist-chart-options="testOptions">
            <svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-bar ct-horizontal-bars" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><g class="ct-grids"><line y1="368" y2="368" x1="50" x2="702" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="279.75" y2="279.75" x1="50" x2="702" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="191.5" y2="191.5" x1="50" x2="702" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="103.25" y2="103.25" x1="50" x2="702" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line x1="50" x2="50" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="109.27272727272728" x2="109.27272727272728" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="168.54545454545456" x2="168.54545454545456" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="227.8181818181818" x2="227.8181818181818" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="287.0909090909091" x2="287.0909090909091" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="346.3636363636364" x2="346.3636363636364" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="405.6363636363636" x2="405.6363636363636" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="464.90909090909093" x2="464.90909090909093" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="524.1818181818182" x2="524.1818181818182" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="583.4545454545455" x2="583.4545454545455" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="642.7272727272727" x2="642.7272727272727" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line><line x1="702" x2="702" y1="15" y2="368" class="ct-grid ct-horizontal"></line></g><g><g class="ct-series ct-series-a"><line y1="323.875" y2="323.875" x1="50" x2="166.17454545454547" class="ct-bar" value="98"></line><line y1="235.625" y2="235.625" x1="50" x2="142.46545454545455" class="ct-bar" value="78"></line><line y1="147.375" y2="147.375" x1="50" x2="229.00363636363636" class="ct-bar" value="151"></line><line y1="59.125" y2="59.125" x1="50" x2="668.8072727272727" class="ct-bar" value="522"></line></g></g><g class="ct-labels"><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="279.75" x="10" height="88.25" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 88px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Other</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="191.5" x="10" height="88.25" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 88px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Windows Phone</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="103.25" x="10" height="88.25" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 88px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">iOS</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="15" x="10" height="88.25" width="30"><span class="ct-label ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 88px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Android</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="50" y="373" width="59.27272727272727" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">0</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="109.27272727272728" y="373" width="59.27272727272727" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">50</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="168.54545454545456" y="373" width="59.272727272727266" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">100</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="227.8181818181818" y="373" width="59.27272727272728" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">150</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="287.0909090909091" y="373" width="59.27272727272728" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">200</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="346.3636363636364" y="373" width="59.27272727272725" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">250</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="405.6363636363636" y="373" width="59.27272727272731" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">300</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="464.90909090909093" y="373" width="59.27272727272725" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">350</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="524.1818181818182" y="373" width="59.27272727272731" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">400</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="583.4545454545455" y="373" width="59.27272727272725" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">450</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="642.7272727272727" y="373" width="59.27272727272725" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 59px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">500</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="702" y="373" width="30" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 30px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">550</span></foreignObject></g></svg></chartist>
```

Here is my directive :

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('chartBarLabel', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            var $chart =  elem.children()[0]; // without [0] it doesn't works too :(
            $chart.append("<p>testerino</p>");

            var tst = elem.parent(); // it works, it get me the parent html
            console.log(tst);
        }
    }
});
```

I also tried to access to the HTML element '.ct-bar' with following pieces :

```
var bar = elem.find('.ct-bar');
var bar2 = angular.element(elem.find(.ct-bar));
var bar3 = angular.element(elem).querySelector('.ct-bar');
```

But none work. The only way I managed to access theses elements are into an event :

```
$chart.on('click', '.ct-bar', function() {
       var bar = $(this);
       bar.append("<label>" +  bar.attr('ct:value') + "</label>");
       console.log("OKKK? ");
});
```

In this case when I click, I correctly append data into bars element. But I want it to be accessed without any event, just by the call of the directive.

**EDIT** : I suspect the svg not being generated when I try accessing elements, but in this case event with a timeout it can't retrieve any child element.

Seems easy, but I swear I'm stuck :(

thanks for your help!

Comment: Chartist or ChartJS miss this kind of feature (putting labels, values or label:values on hover or static on the chart parts). I went back to it and I can't figure it out , I can add a DOM element with the event listener but I can't use events alike the "draw" one, to add it at the page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the SVG not being generated at the time I tried to access elements.

I used $timeout angular component, passed to my directive, and I've done something like this :

```
$timeout(function() {
       var legendValues = [];

       angular.forEach(angular.element(".ct-point"), function(value, key) {
               legendValues.push(angular.element(value).attr('ct:meta'));
       });
       // do other stuff ...
});
```

It took so long for me to figure it out because I already tried this option by setting a setInterval function in which I was trying to access element, and it was not working. But maybe I did it wrong, not using the angular.element wrapper at this particular moment ...